# how to remove data from a object using chrome storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, google-chrome-storage

i have an object stored inside chrome storage that looks like this:

```
{
    "planA": 
    {
        123: {key: 'some key'}
        124: {key: 'some other key'}
    },
    "planB": 
    {
        223: {key: 'some key'}
        234: {key: 'some other key'}
    }
}
```

i want to do something like `chrome.storage.sync.remove([{"planA": "123"}]);`

but that seems not to work `Error in response to storage.get: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Value does not match any valid type choices.`

from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) `StorageArea.remove(string or array of string keys, function callback)`

ant ideas?

Comment: It seems to expect `string or array of string` as parameter. Your first array element is an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in a single API call. The API only gives access to top-level keys: you can get or set `planA` as a whole.

So you'll need to write your own get/set functions, that retrieve the required top-level key, modify the object as required, and save it back.

Comment: yeah, i am gonna go a `get` then remove the sub object and re save it :)