# chrome extension message passing no response-farewell: undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, message-passing

I'm trying to message passing in a chrome extension. I follow this example ([see here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging))- :

content_script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

background:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
});
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
        "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
        console.log("message recive")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Although I did copy-paste - the message is not sent. Error pops up:

Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup does not exist while it's closed.

As such, at the moment when message is sent there is likely no-one listening, so the callback called with `undefined` as response (and with `chrome.runtime.lastError` set).

From an architecture standpoint, the background page is the one always available to process a message; as such, `onMessage` listeners are, in *most* (not all) cases better off in there.

I would recommend taking a look at this question as well, where I explain some concepts in more detail: [Pass a variable from content script to popup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31111721/934239).

*Also, just in case, all this greeting-goodbye sample code is just an example; you can pass anything JSON-serializable.*