# Response function not working in popup.js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a small chrome extension. Right now I'm checking for website language and trying to show that language in `popup.html` but response function is not working and I'm unable to show language in popup. Any help?

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Popup</h1>
        <script src="./scripts/popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "getLanguage"}, function(selectedLanguage) {
    // This function is not working
    if(typeof selectedLanguage == "undefined") {
    } else {
        console.log(selectedLanguage)
    }
})
```

content-script.js
// Content script

```
const pageLanguage = document.querySelector("html").getAttribute('lang');
const language = languages.find(lang => lang.code === pageLanguage); // languages is an array which have all language codes

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'setLanguage', language: language.name});
```

background.js

```
// Background script

// Example of Chrome API use:
chrome.tabs.onCreated = () => {
    console.log('New tab opened');
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (message.type) {
            case 'setLanguage':
                lang = message.language;
                break;
            case 'getLanguage':
                console.log(lang);
                sendResponse(lang);
                break;
        
            default:
                console.error("Unrecognised message: ");
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Answer (score 0):

Try the long lived connections ports which is better for talking between the contentscript and the background page

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect